# Polynomial regression with multilevel data

Tags: multilevel-analysis, polynomial

I want to estimate a polynomial regression to test the effect of self and follower-perception of leadership behavior on some outcome (e.g., followers' job satisfaction). Hence, I have a multilevel data structure with followers' assessments of their supervisors' leadership ($X_1$) as well as followers' job satisfaction ($Y$) on level 1 and supervisors' self-assessment of their leadership behavior ($X_2$) on level 2.

Ignoring the multilevel structure of the data, I would fit the following model:

$$
Job Satisfaction = b_0 + b_1SelfRating + b_2FollowerRating + b_3SelfRaring^2 + b_4SelfRating \times FollowerRating + b_5FollowerRating + e
$$

My question: Can I fit a similar model as a hierarchical linear model? And if yes, are there any things, like mandatory random effects, I have to consider?

In my mind the final model would look (something) like this:

$$
Z_{ij} = \gamma_{00_j} + \gamma_{01_j}Y_j + \gamma_{02_j}Y_j^2 +  \gamma_{10_j}  X_{ij} + \gamma_{11_j}X_{ij}Y_j + \gamma_{20_j}X_{ij}^2 + u_{0_j}+ u_{1_j} + u_{2_j} + e_{ij}
$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The necessity of random effect or hierarchical structure depends on the dependent variable (jobsatisfaction). If dependent variable is independent , then do not need random effect. Your description is not clear enough to judge if the dependent variable is independent or not.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your right. What do you mean with independent? Independent of the nested structure of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article by Nestler, Humberg and Schönbrodt forthcoming in *Psychological Methods* titled "Response surface analysis with multilevel data - Illustration for the case of congruence hypotheses". it is not yet published but you can find the preprint [here](https://www.uni-muenster.de/PsyIFP/AEBack/members/Publications_Humberg.html).

For a case with two level-1 independent variables, they argue for including fixed effects for group-mean centered first-order terms, group-mean centered higher-order terms, and the group means. They also include all possible random effects.

For a case with one level-1 and one level-2 independet variable they advise "to group-mean center the Level 1 congruence variable and including the group-mean-centered Level 1 congruence variable, the Level 2 congruence variable, and the resulting group means in the model to disentangle the Level 1 and Level 2 effects in the response surface analysis."